# Arduino Bluetooth communication issues

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

Based on SDK's bluetoothchat example I'm working on an app that transmits strings between an android device and arduino.
I've the folowing issues:

1- If I use this code I loose the first byte sent by arduino:

```
      // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try { 
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes,-1, buffer).sendToTarget();
```

But This way it works :

```
          bytes = mmInStream.available();
            if(bytes != 0) {
               SystemClock.sleep(100); //pause and wait for rest of data. 
               bytes = mmInStream.available(); // how many bytes are ready to be read?
               bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bytes); // record how many bytes we actually read
               // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
               mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget(); 
             }
```

Any explanation please?

2- Arduino sends the string "OK" when recieves a string from the device.
  How to use this as an ACK(nowledgment) in my app ?

I tried this but with no success:

```
  String ack = ""; //global variable

   sendstring("test string");// send a test string to arduino
   SystemClock.sleep(100); //wait for arduino response
   if(ack.equals("OK")) txtv.setText(" well received"); //well done
```

in the handler:

```
  if(msg.what == Bluetooth.MESSAGE_READ){
 String receivedstring = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, 0, msg.arg1);
 ack = receivedstring ;
```

I don't get ack = "OK" , and " well received" is not displayed in the text view !!

Many thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Hi i dont know that much about blutoothchat but i may have an anwser to your first question. If you dont already have an answer.

```
    // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
    while (true) {
    try { 
    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); // it may not work because its not reading from the first line unlike this: bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bytes);
    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes,-1, buffer).sendToTarget();
```